# Почему не получается создать триггер, который работает с входными данными?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, plsql, триггер

Я имею таблицу A. Она представляет собой список продуктов. В неё я ввожу данные о продуктах. Также у меня имеется таблица B. Это своеобразный склад этих продуктов.
Так вот, один из параметров, который я указываю при вводе данных о продуктах в таблицу A это количество продуктов (`quantity`). И мой триггер проверяет такое условие: если в таблицу A вводится количество продукта, которое больше, чем количество этого же продукта в таблице B, то...
Естественно, чтобы сравнить количество продуктов двух таблиц, нужно эти таблицы как-то связать. Как я их связываю: когда я ввожу данные в таблицу A, то я указываю `prod_id` - это уникальный номер каждого товара. Такой же уникальный номер каждого товара присутствует в таблице B. 
Тот `prod_id`, который я ввожу в таблицу A, в триггере я получаю с помощью `:new.prod_id`. И вот мой триггер:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
BEFORE INSERT ON a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:new.quantity > 
   (SELECT quantity FROM b
    WHERE :new.prod_id = b.prod_id))
THEN
raise_application_error(-20001, 'На складе не присутствует такого количества данного товара!');
END IF;
END;
```

И у меня вылезает ошибка:

```
ORA-24344: success with compilation error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 592
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_SQL", line 1658
ORA-06512: at "SYS.WWV_DBMS_SQL_APEX_190200", line 578
ORA-06512: at "APEX_190200.WWV_FLOW_DYNAMIC_EXEC", line 2057
```

Пожалуйста, помогите решить данную проблему. Что не так с моим триггером и как его правильно написать?

Comment: Потому, что в теле триггера грубые синтаксические ошибки - запрос не может быть частью  IF. Триггер для описанной задачи вообще не нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Перепишите триггер следующим образом:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER t
BEFORE INSERT
ON a
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
l_quantity   NUMBER;
BEGIN
 SELECT quantity
 INTO l_quantity
 FROM b
WHERE :new.prod_id = b.prod_id;

 IF :new.quantity > l_quantity
THEN
  raise_application_error (
     -20001,
     'На складе не присутствует такого количества данного товара!');
END IF;
END;
```